# Macros disabled on Word

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

I don't know why my macros on word is suddenly disabled. I tried everything including placing the template location and my word docs as Trusted locations, Enabling all macros. It still won't run. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

It was running fine this morning. I then wrote a few new macros in the normal.dotm template. I tried running it on a document later and it stated it was disabled.

Comment: Are you using a `.docx` document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't tried restarting your computer, do that. There might be a copy of the Normal template stuck in memory and it needs to clear.